# Import Z3 into Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, z3

Microsoft Research's Z3 Prover can be built using the Visual Studio compilers and `nmake`. This would make it a natural fit to be developed using Visual Studio, and I presume that's what the developers do (or are they actually using Eclipse or whatever?).

However, I couldn't find any instructions on how to import the Z3 source code into Visual Studio. I've got VS2010 Ultimate. Any hints on what to click?

EDIT: I got the code by `git clone https://git01.codeplex.com/z3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I almost always use nmake for building Z3 because I use old-fashioned editors for my work.

You can import Z3 into VS as well. It makes fixing build errors much easier and integration with debugging smoother, though you can still use the VS debugger and performance tools from VS with the executable from nmake.

Following the command-line help, the option for building a vs project is called -v or --vsproj.

```
C:\z3>scripts\mk_make.py --help
mk_make.py: Z3 Makefile generator

This script generates the Makefile for the Z3 theorem prover.
It must be executed from the Z3 root directory.

Options:
  -h, --help                    display this message.
  -s, --silent                  do not print verbose messages.
  --parallel=num                use cl option /MP with 'num' parallel processes
  -b <sudir>, --build=<subdir>  subdirectory where Z3 will be built 
                                (default: build).
   --githash=hash                include the given hash in the binaries.
  -d, --debug                   compile Z3 in debug mode.
  -t, --trace                   enable tracing in release mode.
  -x, --x64                     create 64 binary when using Visual Studio.
  -m, --makefiles               generate only makefiles.
  -v, --vsproj                  generate Visual Studio Project Files.
  -n, --nodotnet                do not generate Microsoft.Z3.dll make rules.
  -j, --java                    generate Java bindinds.
  --staticlib                   build Z3 static library.

Some influential environment variables:
   JDK_HOME   JDK installation directory (only relevant if -j or --java option is provided)
   JNI_HOME   JNI bindings directory (only relevant if -j or --java option is provided)
```

Comment: Editors are nice and less obnoxious than IDEs if you know the code well. If you're new to the code and start hunting for function declarations you're gonna be pretty slow.